# Unable to complete a command from prompt line, using qx in Perl

Tags: perl, prompt, dir, qx

I need my perl program to execute a DIR command in the windows command line.
I use these lines:

```
$percorso1= C:\PerlEsercitazione\FileCompare1\VSS\Divina Cömmediä\ProgettoTest
my $cmd_string = "dir /ad /b ".$percorso1 ;
my @result = qx {$cmd_string};
```

obviously `$percorso1` is the path to follow. The problem is that `@result` turns out to be empty. I typed the DIR command directly in the shell and it works, so the problem should be in the qx function. Where am I wrong?

anyway I tried using readdir ,opendir and closedir but using this code:

```
opendir ("Temp_VSS", $percorso1);
my @result = readdir ($percorso1);
closedir ("Temp_VSS");
```

and I get the error "bad symble for dirhandle"

Comment: Why you do not use the perl readdir function?

Comment: I'm a "newbe" at Perl and I don't know this function...I will look for it in a text book and then I will inform you.

Comment: Whats in `$percorso1`

Comment: $percorso1=  C:\PerlEsercitazione\FileCompare1\VSS\Divina Cömmediä\ProgettoTest

Comment: Please add that code to your question by using the edit option.

Comment: My guess is that you are using double quotes for the path, and that is causing the backslashes to try an interpolate into escape sequences. I also guess that you are not using `use warnings`, or you would already be aware of this problem.

Comment: actually i m using use warnings.....and I haven t understood the rest of your message, sorry... :)...where am I using the doublequotes? I'm not using the doublequotes I suppose...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why does this fail (could be that dir is not really an executable but rather a shell command so you could try with `cmd /c "dir /ad /b $percorso1"`). But generally it's better to avoid external programs for something you have internal functions.

Here specifically [File::Slurp::read_dir](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm#read_dir) can do the same for you much easier and with internal error handling:

```
my @files = File::Slurp::read_dir($percorso1, err_mode => 'carp', keep_dot_dot => 0);
```

Comment: It looks like a good way to avoid the previous problem but....what was the error in my previous attempt?

Comment: Or you could just use `my @files = <$percorso1>`.

Comment: Thank you all. The problem has been fixed. I have replaced qx{} with qx (), and as you have suggested in the other comments I have added the "" aroung the paths.

Answer (score 1):

The $percorso1 declaration is missing the quotes. 
You will need to backslash the backslashes.
The line should end with a semicolon.
Also you will need use utf8; because your source code contains utf8 encoded characters.

For the second snippet look here:
[Perl: Bad Symbol for dirhandle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833120/perl-bad-symbol-for-dirhandle)